# What should do to reduce belly fat who sit in around 8-14 hours per day at office?

Tags: body-fat

I am sit around 8-14 hours per day at office and usually I stand just for lunch and go to the wash room.

What should do to reduce belly fat?

Comment: Totally off topic.

Comment: It might be on topic in the fitness exchange. Read the help center there to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound unfortunately obvious, but exercising and reducing fatty food intake is all you can do to reduce body fat. There's no real trick other than to change your diet and put a time investment into exercise.

Something I've noticed is that it is difficult to maintain a diet while working in an office. It's difficult to focus mentally when you're hungry. I noticed that working manual jobs (I emptied shipping containers for a while) it was easier to eat less since you didn't need to be mentally focused.

That pretty much leaves exercise as your best bet. Is it possible for you to start cycling to work? This is a real 'two birds, one stone' solution. Working full time, you lack the free time to fully dedicate to exercise. Your commute is time wasted as it is, so why not cycle some or all of the way to your office? 
https://www.forbes.com/sites/kevinmurnane/2017/04/25/new-research-indicates-cycling-to-work-has-extraordinary-health-benefits/#7aac183c3e62

It's great for cardio, great for weight loss (the calories you burn are huge), and makes your legs look damn sexy.

Otherwise, swimming is another good option because it exercises your whole body and isn't a huge time sink. You don't need to do a lot to gain huge results. You can swim and hour in the morning/on your lunch/after work and gain a huge amount from it.

Ultimately the key is to cut your diet down and exercise and you should see results in no time. Just doing one or the other may disappoint you, in my own experience, over how slow progress you may make, and cause you to give up, but if you do both for a month or so you'll notice the difference. This should give you a huge confidence and motivational boost to keep going and go harder.

Comment: Thanks Smeato!  Some good info in there.  But I'm interested in your sources for "you've adjusted your diet already, which likely won't make you lose too much weight" as per my understanding, calorie restriction alone is actually more effective in weight loss than exercise is alone.  Of course exercise is important for health and toning and does contribute to weight loss.  But since you put it in an answer, there's a requirement for sources to back up information, and that is a hot topic for discussion.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I have no sources other than my own experience. As such I've updated my question to show this is my personal opinion. Hope this is sufficient!

Comment: @Narusan no worries! Happy to learn too

Comment: I'll +1 but you should remove "fatty" from the first sentence as that's not actually accurate either, it's reducing caloric intake.  Fatty foods are often high calorie, and many fats are unhealthy for other reasons, but within calorie budget, 100 calories of mayonnaise and 100 calories of pasta are not known to be different for losing weight.  At least the evidence hasn't shown it to be so, unless you've found something different.

Answer (score -1):

Don't eat much.

Your body consumes about 2500 calories per day. You can get a more precise estimate by adding three factors, the Basal Metabolic Rate (BRM), [calories consumed by activity](http://www.nutristrategy.com/caloriesburned.htm) and food processing calorie consumption.

> Adult male: 66 + (6.3 x body weight in lbs.) + (12.9 x height in
>   inches) - (6.8 x age in years)
>
> Adult female: 655 + (4.3 x weight in lbs.) + (4.7 x height in inches)
>   - (4.7 x age in years)

So, for example, if you weigh 200 pound, are 5'10", male and 40 years old, then your estimated BMR is 66 + (6 * 200) + (12.9 * 70) - (6.8 * 40 ) = 1957 calories. If we add in 300 calories for walking around and 200 calories for processing food (10% of the food consumed), then the total is around 2500 calories. A weight loss diet could be, for example, half of that, which 1250 calories per day. A person with this nutrition profile will steadily lose fat if they eat below 2500 calories per day.

The rate of weight loss depends on how big the caloric deficit is. So, in the above example, a person with a 2500 requirement and a 1250 diet will lose about 1250 calories per day. A pound of body fat will generate about 3500 calories of energy. That means with a 1250 deficit, the person will lose 1/3 pound per day, or 10 pounds every month.

Comment: So this is a good way to answer a question, except for a couple things.  (1) you need resources. That's a nutrition website for activities, which is okay, I mean for the calculator and other assertions.  (2) Calculators sometimes (or even often) overestimate, studies have shown this.  The average for some populations BMR is closer to 1500.  Example this estimates my BMR at 1923; formally measured, mine measured was 1190.  If I ate my calculated BMR, that 730 difference is a pound gained every 5 days.  Let alone +500 for activity.  I would recommend adding a discussion that it varies widely.